# Advice for an asynchronous programming problem in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous

I have a set of classes which encapsulate a unit of work on Google Sheets. After the class's execute method is called, they pass a request to a service, bundled with a callback which the service should call on task completion. (As the tasks are non-critical and repeated frequently, the service just logs errors and does not call the class back if its request fails).

Stripped down, the tasks look like this:

```
public void execute() {
  //preparatory stuff, then...
  Request r = new Request(this::callback);
  service.execute(r);
}

public void callback(Result result) {
  ...
}
```

The call to the service is synchronous but within the service, the Request is queued, executed asynchronously, and the callback is invoked on a new thread. Some of the tasks involve several service invocations, the callback methods may themselves create a Request with a second callback method and invoke the service again. I want that to be invisible to client code.

My problem now is that I would like to run the tasks asynchronously from client code and then execute an arbitrary handler after they are done. One way to do this would be to give the class a callback in the execute() method for it to call once execution is complete. But I'd really rather be able to do this inline in code, this sort of thing:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> (new Task()).execute()).whenComplete((result, error) -> {});
```

The problem with that is, the completion of the execute() method does not signal the end of the task, as the task is still awaiting its callback. The other thing is, that callback might never arrive. I can't figure out how I should go about calling the task such that I can run it asynchronously and inline like in the code above and the whenComplete() will be invoked when the Task class explicitly decides it is finished. I'd also need a timeout, as the tasks's callback may not be invoked.

Any ideas? Note that I control the service invoked by the tasks, so I can change how that works if necessary, but I'd probably rather not.

Comment: I work with Java Swing, so I'm used to the idea of an ActionListener being invoked when a user left-clicks on a JButton.  You could create your own EventListener for the callback method.  Here's an article I wrote about EventListeners.  https://web.archive.org/web/20130507164841/http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=150

Answer (score 0):

I'd spend some time looking around in java.util.concurrent. Can't you just use an ExecutorService for a lot of this? You can submit() Callable code and get a future back, you can submit a list of Callables and give a timeout, you can call shutdown() and then awaitTermination() to wait for the processing to stop. You can get these notification callbacks by just submitting a Callable that constructs with the callback interface and invokes it when it feelsl like it's done.

Failing this, you might look at actors. Your concurrency pattern would likely be very easy in the actor model.

Answer (score 0):

Going to answer my own question here: I just altered the task execute methods to return a `CompletableFuture<TaskResult>` with TaskResult containing the desired information. The task stores the `CompletableFuture` internally and calls `complete()` as needed in later callbacks. Not sure why I had trouble seeing this solution.